# Does iPhone's new HEVC video format also halve file size for 720p and 1080p?

Tags: iphone

I've learnt the HEVC format halves storage space of recorded 4K videos.  Does it also halve the space if you record in 1080p and 720p?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, iOS 11 supports lower resolutions HEVC resolutions as well.

Please note that the bit rate reduction will be lower at lower resolutions. The setting Settings > Camera > Formats is a global setting an will affect video and photo capture at the same time.

Source: [Wikipedia/TK Tan; Marta Mrak; Vittorio Baroncini; Naeem Ramzan (2014-05-18)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding#cite_ref-HEVCMay2014Q1011_97-0)